# How to read/send post data with php and hold a variable in it

Tags: php, sql

I have this code in a loop in my code, The loop makes one submit button for every member found. I need each button to have the members name stored in it, in a way it can be sent though post when that button is clicked. Im not sure if this is possible with post but i was trying a way i do it with URLS. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
<input type="submit" value="Attack" name="Attack?name=<?php echo $Member_name; ?>" />

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['Attack'])){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'])."'";
$query = mysql_query($sql)  or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_object($query);
}
```

Here is the whole code i was trying to store it in a hidden form but it only grabs the last member found and wont get others.

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT name, rank FROM users ORDER BY rank DESC"; //  Searches the database for every one who has being last active in the last 5 minute
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
 $Member_name = htmlspecialchars($row->name);
$Member_level = htmlspecialchars($row->rank);
?>
<td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
<td><a href="View_Profile.php?name=<?php echo $Member_name; ?>"><?php echo $Member_name; ?></a></td><td><?php echo $Member_level; ?></td><td>
<input type="hidden" name="thename" value="<?php echo $Member_name; ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Attack" name="Attack" />
</td>
<?

 if($i != $count) { // this counts the amount of people that are online and display the results.
  echo "</tr><tr>";
 }
 $i++;
}
?>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['Attack'])){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['thename'])."'";
$query = mysql_query($sql)  or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_object($query);
$profile_id = htmlspecialchars($row->id);
$profile_userip = htmlspecialchars($row->userip);
$profile_name = htmlspecialchars($row->name);
$profile_money = htmlspecialchars($row->money);
$profile_gang = htmlspecialchars($row->gang);
$profile_exp = htmlspecialchars($row->exp);
$profile_profile = htmlspecialchars($row->profile);
$profile_rank = htmlspecialchars($row->rank);
$profile_health = htmlspecialchars($row->health);
$profile_defence = htmlspecialchars($row->defence);
$profile_stanima = htmlspecialchars($row->stanima);
?>
```

Comment: "**like 10 buttons**" so they may not be buttons ? or perhaps not 10 of them ?

Comment: its a loop for each member there is right now there is 10 but if someone else makes a character there will be 11 buttons then

Comment: if you could show the whole loop it would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, assuming everything else is working ok, and you are retrieving data.

Change this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="thename" value="<?php echo $Member_name; ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Attack" name="Attack" />
```

To this:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $Member_name; ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Attack" name="Attack" />
</form>
```

And also in your PHP, change this line:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'])."'";
```

To:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST ['name'])."'";
```

***This isn't the best way to do this,*** you will be generating loads of HTML elements depending how many users you have, but it should solve you problem (providing everything else is working and receiving data).

HTML 5 & Javascript would be perfect for this and is something you should look into.

Comment: thanks it worked! i had the form code above the loop dident think it had to be there. im not sure about html 5 and javascript i want my game to work good on mobile and old desktops. i think i could limit it to 10 members per page. or something like that